# Deploy EJB2 on Weblogic 10.3

Tags: weblogic, ejb-2.x

I try to deploy ejb2 on weblogic 10.3 but I face a problem the deployed ear can't see new methods added to any ejb session bean. I added the method to remote interface and I added the implementation to bean class. I hope anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Is it only the modified EJB2 which is not reflecting changes? Was an original one working? Did you try restarting the server or only hot depolyed?

Comment: i did restarted the server and the original one is working

Answer (score 0):

I believe WebLogic 10.3 supports EJB3, so you'll have to do some modification.  You already have the evidence to prove it.

Comment: There are old methods that run successfully. But when I add new one it can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the old EJBs are working, but it's not reflecting updated methods - I think this is cached.

Drill down on your server to the following path or a similar one

`DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\cache\EJBCompilerCache`

There will be many folders in there with random names like `ff7i19ot3cg6` and `l443b5vws35h`

Clear out all these folders and redeploy the app

Comment: I did so, but I dont know why still the same problem exist :(